# C# LINQ Projecting to a class

Tags: c#, linq

I call a web service and I get a response object back in JSON.

I would like the results in a list so I can enumerate through them.

So I have this piece of code which works as intended.

```
var players = getPlayersResponse.Payload
  .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Pid, p.Model, p.Ip, p.Gid })
  .ToList();
foreach (var p in players)
{
    Players.Items.Add(p.Name);
}
```

I would like to return a list of a known class instead so have tried following:

```
var players = getPlayersResponse.Payload
  .Select(p => new Player { Name= p.Name, Pid= p.Pid, Model= p.Model, Ip= p.Ip, Gid= (int)p.Gid })
  .ToList();    
foreach (var p in players)
{
    Players.Items.Add(p.Name);
}
```

And the class

```
public class Player
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Pid { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }
  public string Ip { get; set; }
  public int Gid { get; set; }
}
```

That version do not work (listbox is not populated with items) and I get no errors at all and compiler do not complain. Strangely though the complier did complain if I did not cast p.Gid to int. It is the same json result in both cases.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what's in `players` in each case? There's nothing obviously wrong there...

Comment: can you put your code on .Net Fiddle?

Comment: @Jon yes I have, In first case players have items in second case not.

Comment: That sounds very odd indeed - but it's going to be hard to help any further without being able to reproduce the problem. Could provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: I think I found out what the problem was. Mouseover tip on p.Gid displayed type as int? I did not know what that meant so to be able to compile I casted to int and that at least satishdfied the compiler. I just tried to remove that cast again and in my class change Gid from int to int? and now I get the results as I expects.

Comment: That wouldn't explain getting an empty list though. I could understand if it had thrown an exception, but not just an empty list. It's hard to know what else to say without a complete example.

Comment: @JonSkeet from the context (a listbox getting populated) it's possible that this is running in an async event handler (i. e. `async void`) - that would swallow the exception, right?

Comment: @germi: If the OP was looking in the debugger, they wouldn't get to see an empty `players` variable, because it wouldn't get that far.

Comment: Can you please provide Sample of json you get?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the class like this

```
public class Player
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Pid { get; set; }
   public string Model { get; set; }
   public string Ip { get; set; }
   public int? Gid { get; set; }
}
```